# Try to create .bat file to zip reports on network drive

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Have 2 drives:

- network drive, where reports are located
- Local disk, where 7zip is located.

Also, we have many users, everybody mapped network drive with different letter. Hence, the path to report will not be the same for everyone.

Script and reports located in the same folder.
Try to create script.bat to archive reports on network drive. Here is what I have:

```
@echo off

::set a path to network shared directory

pushd \\IP_address\path_to_reports
set BEpath= %cd%

:: Move files to temporary directory FilesToZip

mkdir "%BEpath%\FilesToZip"

move %BEpath%\report_Germany_??_%1_??.txt %BEpath%\FilesToZip\

:: Archive files

cd /d "C:\Program Files\7-Zip"

7z a -t7z "%BEpath%\archive.7z" "%BEpath%\FilesToZip\*.txt"
```

If I use just `CD \\server\path` instead of `pushd \\IP_address\path_to_reports` it gives error

`CMD does not support UNC paths as current directories.`

Looks like it can not zip on network drive from C:\ drive and gives error:

```
7-Zip 19.00 (x64) : Copyright (c) 1999-2018 Igor Pavlov : 2019-02-21

Scanning the drive:

WARNING: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
 Z:

0 files, 0 bytes

Creating archive:  Z:\path\archive.7z

Add new data to archive: 0 files, 0 bytes


Scan WARNINGS for files and folders:

 Z: : The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
----------------
Scan WARNINGS: 1

Error:
cannot open file
 Z:\path\archive.7z
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Could you advice, how it can be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

7z supports UNC path natively.

Instead of trying to use the temp drive created by pushd:

```
7z a -t7z "%BEpath%\archive.7z" "%BEpath%\FilesToZip\*.txt"
```

Use the UNC path directly:

```
set "UNCpath=\\IP_address\path_to_reports"
7z a -t7z "%UNCpath%\archive.7z" "%UNCpath%\FilesToZip\*.txt"
```

Comment: move your double quotes in the set string to include the variable name `set "UNCpath=\\IP_address\path_to_reports"`

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard, thanks for the catch.   It tested okay, so I didn't even notice the typo.    Updated.

Comment: Tank you guys.  `"UNCpath=\\IP_address\path_to_reports"` - worked.

Answer (score -1):

You have a couple options.

1) You can parse the output of `wmic logicaldisk get caption,drivetype,providername` for `drivetype`=4 (network drive) where `providername`='\IP_address\path_to_reports'. Then `caption` will have their mapped drive letter for your use directly. Be aware that `WMIC` is deprecated so this approach will someday stop working for you.

2) You can just remap it yourself to an unlikely letter. I find that almost nobody uses `A:`.

```
net use a: \\IP_address\path_to_reports
set BEpath=a:\

...do stuff here...

net use a: /delete
```